# PyQt NameError when calling my scripts

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

i keep getting this error but according to my textbook and previous script there should not be a problem

```
    import sys
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
    from welcome import *
    class MyForm(QtGui.QDialog):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
            self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)
            QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.ClickMeButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.dispmessage)

        def dispmessage(self):
            self.ui.labelMessage.setText("Hello " + self.ui.lineUserName.text())

        if __name__=="__main__":
            app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
            myapp = MyForm()
            myapp.show()
            sys.exit(app.exec_())
**ERROR**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4/callwelc.py", line 4, in <module>
    class MyForm(QtGui.QDialog):
  File "C:/Python33/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4/callwelc.py", line 16, in myform
    myapp = MyForm()
NameError: name 'MyForm' is not defined
```

Comment: Move the `if __name__` block outside your class definition.

Answer (score 0):

You have the `if __name__` block inside your class definition. That means that the interpreter tries to execute it before the `MyForm` class has finished being defined.

Fix the indentation so the `if __name__` block lies *outside* the class definition.

```
class MyForm(QtGui.QDialog):
    ... insides of class here

if __name__=="__main__":
    ...
```